# AutoResetEvent.WaitOne with timeout vs Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, waithandle

I need a solution to perform arbitrary pause. The delay accuracy is irrelevant. What is the practical difference in such scenario between [WaitHandle.WaitOne Method (TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Thread.Sleep Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Are there any better solutions?

Comment: 'Better' depends on the circumstances. Waiting is basically wrong so no 'best practice' here.

Comment: What is bad in waiting when all I need is only waiting? I just wonder which method is better from performance perspective or if they behave in the same manner under the hood, then I will make my decision basing on other factors such as readability.

Comment: Why would you create an `AutoResetEvent`, call `WaitOne`, dispose the event, when you can simply do `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: @Henrik I can invoke _WaitOne_ many times in the loop without disposing _AutoResetEvent_. What would be the difference then? Ok, one minus is that I need to create an instance of wait handle, but I do that only once, so it is negligible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your spec says something like 'Always wait at least two seconds before continuing', use Sleep().

If your spec says something like 'Wait for up to two seconds for a signal from another thread and return an error if timed out' use an event object.

It's basically that simple.

There are essentially no 'performance differences' re. timing accuracy since both calls use the same mechanism for timeouts.

'Better' solutions - what is 'better'?  Better in what respect?

Answer (score 10):

1.Thread.Sleep(timeout) causes an unconditional wait before execution is resumed.

2.WaitOne(timeout) causes the thread to wait until either

- the event is triggered,
- The timeout is reached

Comment: Then what is your proposition? Should I use 1st or 2nd?

Comment: It's depends on your requirements.I always prefer signal based synchronization eg.WaitOne

Comment: Where is the part that telling about performance difference between waiting in 1st or 2nd manner?

Comment: My problem with Sleep is that when you want to cancel it, you need to raise an exception when killing the thread. With the signal, you can cancel it more beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue against ever using `Thread.Sleep(...)`... simply because I dislike blocking a thread unnecessarily...  So using a `WaitHandle` I think is the superior option.

**Alternative**

If you're code's elegance will suffer from using `WaitHandle`, then have you considered `await Task.Delay(...)`?  This will give functionality simliar to `Thread.Sleep(...)` without blocking the thread.

Comment: ?? Waiting on an event handle blocks the thread, just like sleep() calls.

Comment: @MartinJames But without blocking the thread... `Task.Delay()` actually uses a timer.

Comment: Asynchronous execution on another thread, eg. by Task.Delay(), is surely possible, but the OP is asking about synchronous delays in the calling thread.